# Exoplayer 4k Video Out of Memory

Tags: android, out-of-memory, exoplayer

I want to play a local 4k video file via exoplayer on a rockchip tv box. Full HD videos are working fine. Also most 4k videos are playing smoothly. But a few 4k videos are extremely lagging and than the playback freezes with an out of memory error.

The exoplayer demo app is playing the file without any problem. My app does a lot of other things like downloading the video files, having a open websocket connection etc. therefore it uses of course more memory than the demo app. However it should play the file too.

Logs:

```
   D/EventLogger: videoSize [eventTime=1.49, mediaPos=0.00, window=0, period=0, 3840, 2160]
2022-11-11 11:21:32.323 13639-13639/com.example.package D/EventLogger: renderedFirstFrame [eventTime=1.49, mediaPos=0.00, window=0, period=0, Surface(name=null)/@0x1dcfafd]
2022-11-11 11:21:32.341 13639-13639/com.example.package D/EventLogger: state [eventTime=1.51, mediaPos=0.05, window=0, period=0, READY]
2022-11-11 11:21:32.341 13639-13639/com.example.package I/VideoFragment: onPlayerStateChanged: 3
2022-11-11 11:21:32.342 13639-13639/com.example.package D/EventLogger: isPlaying [eventTime=1.51, mediaPos=0.05, window=0, period=0, true]
2022-11-11 11:21:32.610 13639-13650/com.example.package I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 203MB to 192MB
2022-11-11 11:21:32.636 13639-13714/com.example.package I/art: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
2022-11-11 11:21:32.644 13639-13714/com.example.package I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 7.544ms for cause Alloc
2022-11-11 11:21:32.644 13639-13714/com.example.package I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
2022-11-11 11:21:32.644 13639-13714/com.example.package I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
```

A lot more of blocking GC Alloc logs...

```
022-11-11 11:10:51.403 13452-13535/com.example.package E/LoadTask: OutOfMemory error loading stream
      java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 65548 byte allocation with 53032 free bytes and 51KB until OOM
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultAllocator.allocate(DefaultAllocator.java:102)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.SampleDataQueue.preAppend(SampleDataQueue.java:233)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.SampleDataQueue.sampleData(SampleDataQueue.java:176)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.SampleQueue.sampleData(SampleQueue.java:590)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.TrackOutput.sampleData(TrackOutput.java:157)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.mp4.Mp4Extractor.readSample(Mp4Extractor.java:652)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.mp4.Mp4Extractor.read(Mp4Extractor.java:259)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.BundledExtractorsAdapter.read(BundledExtractorsAdapter.java:127)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ProgressiveMediaPeriod.java:1039)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:412)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

If I transcoce the videos they are playing without any problems.

Comment: Have you released the player in the 'onDestroy()' of an activity?

Comment: Yes I did that too. The error is occurring 5 to 20 minutes after I booted the device. So onDestroy never got called in this time.

Comment: I was having the same problem..Then I realised that I have forgot to release the player while navigating back from an activity, I released the player in onDestroy & it worked. So.

Comment: I have issue with the TV ExoPlayer it's 1920x1080 and it's lag it's not even 4K. And I have only 2 minute video and it's play in loop.

Comment: I dont think thats the same error, but we fixed a similar error by checking the used media codec. We forced the exo player to use the rockchip codec on our tv boxes.